# get value of Dynamic textarea by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/3QeSe/44/     i am getting undefined any help appreciated ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You seem to be attempting to use `$(this)` directly inside the `document.ready` handler. May I ask why and what's the purpose?

Comment: You can't get textarea id by var Id = element.attr("id");

Comment: What are you expecting to get by calling `element.attr("id")` when not defining `element`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3QeSe/50/

Comment: i tried $("#publiccontent" + Id).val(); also and .html() also not coming ....see my full script on http://pastebin.com/MtepkVQi       when textarea created dynamically it not fetching value it gives undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `val()` not `.html()` to fetch the value of `textarea`

**EDITED:**  (after OP has put more info)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72jNj/)

**Markup:**

```
<textarea name="text" class="checkthis" id="publiccontent22">Some text here</textarea>
```

​

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.checkthis').blur(function(){

    var test = $(this).val();

    if (test == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else {
        alert(test);
    }

  });
});​
```

Comment: i tried $("#publiccontent" + Id).val(); also and .html() also not coming see my full script  on http://pastebin.com/MtepkVQi  ... when textarea created dynamically it not fetching value

Comment: i want to use by id  .. id is dynamic and textarea and button also dynamic  not by class kindly see  my code on   http://pastebin.com/MtepkVQi

Comment: Do you want something like this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72jNj/1/) ?    If yes, I guess `22` is not a valid value for `id` attribute.

Comment: 22 is dynamic value it keep on changing while generating textareaid name...    <textarea style="height:50px"  id="publiccontent<?php echo $ochatresult->id; ?>"  name="publictext"></textarea><br />

Comment: I am not using '22' anywhere to select `textarea`. Better try to understand how I am selecting elements. And if that doesnt help. Rephrase your question and put a small snippet of your 'full' code in question

Comment: You can select like this,

`$('#publiccontent<?php echo $ochatresult->id; ?>')`. Its perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea had no value. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3QeSe/49/

Also, try inserting the code in your post instead of only in your jsfiddle.

You also need to define element to make this dynamic, perhaps by adding a class to the element and get the ID if any element matching that class was modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/3QeSe/57/

```
<textarea name="text" class="checkthis" id="publiccontent22">Some text here</textarea>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.checkthis').blur(function(){

    var test = $(this).html();

    if (test == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else {
        alert(test);
    }

});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/Zg87Z/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = $("#publiccontent22").val();

    alert(test);
    if (test == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else {
        alert(test);
    }
});
```